# Идентификатор клиента 1С пересчитывается на машинах Linux, слетают настройки касс. Как предотвратить?

Tags: linux, 1с

Как расчитывается идентификатор клиента в Линукс? Я переодически получаю новый идентификатор и соответственно слетают настройки касс.

Как зафиксировать его жестко?

Comment: А файл 1cv8u.pfl на линуксе так же есть с прописанным айди? Или там другая система?

Comment: @PotroNik есть файл с айди, но он пересчитывается при запуске. Раз в месяц, случайно, получаю новый айди на некоторых машинках. Я пробовал менять тот файл на старый. Сегодня посмотрю то ли имя у файла или с другим работал

Comment: 1) После остановки сервера, файл остается на месте?
2) Может оставить доступ только на чтение 0444?

Comment: @p-c это айди клиента. Сервер на другой машине. Остается на месте. Если поставить только чтение - он игнорируется

Comment: @eri
>"есть файл с айди, но он пересчитывается при запуске. Раз в месяц, случайно, получаю новый айди на некоторых машинках."

Получается, при запуске клиента раз в месяц пересчитывается?
Если только на чтение - игнорит и кассу не запускает? Может попробовать файл рядом положить и сделать на него симлинк, а самому файлу только чтение прописать? Но это костыли. Не может быть такого, что сервер шлет новый id кассе и та его переписывает и ломается (ну а вдруг, настройка там какая-нибудь)? P.s. с 1с почти не работал

Comment: Может привязывает к версии ядра или ещё чего-то... Симлинки не помогают тоже